# Angular JS. Refresh a list after promise completes

Tags: angularjs, rest, promise

I have a model that I am using to hold my data in angular:

```
var FuelProcessingModel = function (carrierService) {
    this.myArray = [];
};
```

That model has an array of MyObjects that I get from the DB:

```
var MyObject = function () {
    //stuff
}
```

I update this using a REST call:

```
$scope.add = function () {
        var myObject = new MyObject();
        $scope.model.MyObjects.push(myObject);
        service.add(myObject);
    };
```

Which I use a service to hit the Server:

```
this.add = function (myObject) {
        $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "theServer",
            data: myObject
        });
    }
```

The REST service just adds to the database, It doesn't return anything.
I need to reload the data from the database after the update is finished, so that my records now have all newly associated ID's and pertinent data.

I cannot just do:

```
window.location.reload();
```

The user starts by selecting a value from a drop down list to decide which list of data they start off seeing. I cannot / do not want to pass the value to it, mainly because it is in its own partial view, with its own controller, because it is used on many pages.

I tried doing:

```
$scope.add = function () {
        //same as above
        //this
        service.get().then(function(result) { $scope.model.myArray = result.data; });
    };
```

Obviously the problem here is the promise isn't complete before the DOM reloads the page. So the user saw themself add an item to the array and it vanished.

Do I want to load the page after the promise is complete? (How would I do that?)
should I return the updated data from the REST service and reset the current value? (seems like the same promise issue)

Is there a better practice that I do not know about?

**UPDATE**

For Bergi:

```
this.get = function (key) {
        return $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "theServer" + key
        })
            .success(function (data) {
                return data;
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to chain your two promises:

```
$scope.add = function () {
    var myObject = new MyObject();
    $scope.model.MyObjects.push(myObject);
    return service.add(myObject).then(function() {
        return service.get();
    }).then(function(result) {
        $scope.model.myArray = result.data;
    });
};
```

and

```
this.add = function(myObject) {
    return $http({
//  ^^^^^^ return a promise here
        method: "POST",
        url: "theServer",
        data: myObject
    });
};
```

Comment: I updated my code, are you saying I should put the return of the first promise where the comment is?

Comment: @Robert: Yes, [no deferreds needed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572) at all.

Comment: With my code above, would you have two return statements? Could you put an example of it?

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your service call in a deferred promise, and on return success re-init your data from the controller..

```
$scope.add = function () {
    var myObject = new MyObject();
    $scope.model.MyObjects.push(myObject);
    service.add(myObject).then(function (response) {
       // here's where you'd do whatever you want to refresh your model
    }),
    function (err) {console.log(err);};
};
```

And the service:

```
this.add = function (myObject) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "theServer",
        data: myObject,
        success: function (response) {
           deferred.resolve(err);
        },
        error: function (err) {
           deferred.reject(err);
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: in order to use this my REST controller would have to send back some sort of acknowledgement that it was successful right?

Comment: @Robert, correct-a-mundo, for simplicity you could just send back a 200 OK on success or 400 on failure. What's your back-end in?

Comment: Don't use the deferred antipattern! No need to instantiate deferreds here! Btw, you're not returning anything?

Comment: @Bergi I am not returning anything from the server, currently but I can change that.

Comment: @Robert: That comment was aimed at JoshuaOhana, his service function doesn't really work

Comment: @Bergi TIL :) Thanks and agreed (now that I've researched), feel free to post the proper answer and I'll upvote

Comment: @JoshuaOhana: Already did :-) My answer calls `service.add` *and* `service.get` though, not sure whether that's a good practise in angular.

Comment: Where does $q come from, I injected it into my service and it errored

Comment: @Robert, AngularJS...... .factory('myService', ($q, $http... see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q